# How can I use keras if I have different input_shape on input image

Tags: python, keras

I want to use keras to make a CNN construct, but my input images' shape will different. After I use small input shape to learning, I recognize image shape will also different.

```py
input_shape = (None, None, 3)

model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3,3), input_shape=input_shape, padding='same', activation='relu'))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(2,2))

model.add(Conv2D(128, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu'))

model.add(Conv2D(128, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu'))

model.add(MaxPooling2D(2,2))

model.add(Conv2D(256, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu'))

model.add(Conv2D(256, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu'))

model.add(Conv2D(256, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu'))

model.add(MaxPooling2D(2,2))

model.add(Conv2D(512, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu'))

model.add(Conv2D(512, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu'))

model.add(Conv2D(512, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu'))

model.add(MaxPooling2D(2,2))

model.add(Conv2D(512, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu'))

model.add(Conv2D(512, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu'))

model.add(Conv2D(512, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu'))

model.add(MaxPooling2D(2,2))

model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(4000, activation='relu'))

model.add(Dense(4000, activation='relu'))

model.add(Dense(30, activation='relu'))
```

But the program execute to "Flatten()" error. What can I use? Thanks you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You should reshape to some nice square shape...